# Remove whitespace in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code for move text from cell to cell

```
Dim startIndex As Integer
Dim toIndex As Integer
Dim f As String
Dim g As String

For startIndex = 50 To 60 Step 2
toIndex = Str(startIndex + 1)
f = "F" & Str(toIndex)
g = "G" & Str(startIndex)
Range(f).Value = Range(g).Value
Range(g).Value = ""
Next startIndex
```

But variable f has "F 51" value instead of "F51".

How solve this problem ?
p.s. It's my first code on vba.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `TRIM()` the `toIndex` or `REPLACE` spaces in the end result, i.e.

```
Replace ("alphabet", "a", "e")  'would return "elphebet"
```

example lifted from here: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace.php

So...

```
f = Replace (f, " ", "")
```

Comment: For those wondering, ```Trim()``` will only remove the leading and trailing white-space characters, not spaces between words.

Answer (score 16):

You should be using
`CStr`
not
`Str`

Then no workaround is needed for removing an unncessary space

ie

```
 f = "F" & CStr(toIndex)
 g = "G" & CStr(startIndex)
```

From Excel help for `Str`

> When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always reserved for the sign of number.

Comment: +1 for getting to the core issue.  Also change to `toIndex = startIndex + 1` or do away with `toIndex` by using `f = "F" & CStr(startIndex + 1)`