# Unable to kick out whitespaces around and in between a string

Tags: excel, vba, whitespace

I'm trying to kick out whitespaces around and in between a string. The thing is I know I can get rid of `leading` and `trailing` whitespaces by using `Trim()` but I can't remove the same located between words of a string. However, If I go for `Replace()` then no whitespaces are there which is even worse.

I tried with:

```
Sub KickOutWhitespaces()
    itemstr = "   hi    there    sam  "

    Debug.Print Trim(itemstr)
    Debug.Print Replace(itemstr, " ", "")
End Sub
```

Output I'm getting:

```
hi    there    sam
hitheresam
```

What I wish to get:

```
hi there sam
```

I checked out this two answers [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574000/remove-whitespace-in-vba-excel) and [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48619282/delete-whitespaces-vba-excel) but those didn't help me solve this.

***How can I get rid of whitespaces using vba?***

Comment: Instead of just `Trim` use `WorksheetFunction.Trim`

Comment: @tigeravatar - Will that help remove multiple spaces within the text?  Could you use replace? Without getting in to Regex (which could likely work much quicker/easier, can you do `Replace(imemstr, "  *", " ")` (that's two spaces and an asterisk for the find, and the replacement is a single space)  Edit: ...nope, that doesn't work.

Comment: @BruceWayne You should try both and check out the results.

Comment: @BruceWayne, `WorksheetFunction.Trim` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RegEx:

```
Sub repl()
Dim myRegExp As RegExp

Set myRegExp = New RegExp
Dim itemstr As String

myRegExp.Global = True
' The pattern is two spaces followed by an asterisk
myRegExp.Pattern = "  *"

itemstr = "   hi    there    sam  "

Dim finalStr As String
finalStr = Trim(myRegExp.Replace(itemstr, " "))
Debug.Print finalStr
End Sub
```

<sub>You will need the RegEx Reference.</sub>

Edit: Whelp, this is overkill. As commented, you can just do `Worksheetfunction.trim(itemstr)`

Comment: I tried with `WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim(itemstr))` but that didn't help either. However, this `Worksheetfunction.trim(itemstr)` did the trick @BruceWayne. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Trim(" ")` and then `Replace("  ", " ")` to replace 2 consecutive spaces by 1 space.

All instances of 2 consecutive spaces will be replaced by a single space.

Comment: If there are five spaces, wouldn't this then leave extra space still between text?